# Local snmpwalk fails with Unknown Object Identifier, but remote works

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I observe a problem with `net-snmp` while retrieving a subtree
with snmpwalk locally:

On the Target Host itself I got a `Unknown Object Identifier Error Message`.

```
snmpwalk -v3 -m ALL -M /usr/share/snmp/mibs -n "" -u admin -a SH
A -A "12345678" -x AES -X "12345678" -l authPriv localhost TAINY-MIB::tainyMIBObjects
TAINY-MIB::tainyMIBObjects: Unknown Object Identifier (TAINY-MIB::tainyMIBObjects)
```

The same `snmpwalk` from a remote Host to the Target is just working fine:

```
snmpwalk -v3 -m ALL -M /home/graute/snmp/mibs/ -n "" -u admin -a SHA -A "12345678" -x AES -X "12345678" -l authPriv 192.168.1.8:161 TAINY-MIB::tainyMIBObj
ects                                                                                                                                                                                      
TAINY-MIB::tainyCSQ = INTEGER: 99
TAINY-MIB::tainyLACCID = ""
TAINY-MIB::tainyWirelessWANIP = ""
TAINY-MIB::tainyAccessTechnology = INTEGER: 0
```

I double checked that the MIB files exists on the target machine in
 `/usr/share/snmp/mibs`. I copied these files directly form the
remote hosts. I also using the `-M` option

Somebody a clue whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

On the first version `snmpwalk` can't find the symbol in the MIBs you are providing, before trying to contact the SNMP agent.

Try `snmptranslate  -m ALL -M /usr/share/snmp/mibs  -On TAINY-MIB::tainyMIBObjects` and I expect that you won't get a lookup in the MIB, whereas it will work on the other host.

If so, check the -M path for the local MIBs lookup and ensure the MIB files  identical in both environments (e.g. both files contain the symbol you are looking for)

Comment: I checked that both files are identical and both files contain the  tainyMIBObjects but its still not working on the Target

Comment: Does snmptranslate  work on both (that does not involve contacting the agent )?

Comment: On the target the snmptranslate don´t work with same error , but it work from the host side

Comment: Is every file in the two directories identical? What happens if you do 'grep tainyMIBObjects *' in each ?

Comment: I got on the host and the target the same output grep tainyMIBObjects *
TAINY-MIB.txt:tainyMIBObjects OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { tainyMIB 1 }
TAINY-MIB.txt:    ::= { tainyMIBObjects 1 }
...
TAINY-MIB.txt:    ::= { tainyMIBObjects 52 }

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the problem above was the wrong compile option

```
--disable-mib-loading
```

instead of

```
--enable-mib-loading
```

changing this fixed my problem.